# Why does my Swift bundle get the wrong principal class?

Tags: swift, nsbundle

I made a bundle target, and its `Info.plist` file specifies that a very specific class (let's call it `PrincipalClass`) should be its principal class. This class was written in Swift and has the `@objc` attribute. The `Info.plist` file is correctly copied over to the bundle, and I have cleaned and rebuilt the project multiple times already.

However, when I load the bundle from my Swift framework, its principal class is a different class (let's call it `NotPrincipalClass`). It was not marked `@objc`, and in fact, it should be internal to the bundle. I checked `bundle.bundleURL` in the debugger, and the `Info.plist` file in the bundle does say that it should be `PrincipalClass`; but when I check `bundle.infoDictionary`, the `NSPrincipalClass` attribute reads `NotPrincipalClass` as a string! (The info dictionary also contains several keys that were not specified by the `Info.plist` file, like `DTCompiler` and such.)

If I entirely remove `NotPrincipalClass`, I get another internal class instead, which is still totally not my principal class.

I checked the build logs thoroughly and I saw no mention of `NotPrincipalClass`, except when it got compiled.

What could cause this? What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somehow, using its qualified name instead ("PlugInNamespace.PrincipalClass") solved the problem, but this has me very skeptical because I have another plugin that does not requires this.