# Deleting test database in Vapor 3

Tags: swift, vapor

I want to write some integration tests for Vapor 3 server and I need to have clean Postgre database each time I run my tests. How can I achieve this? It seems migrations isn't the right way to go as they've been running once if database doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Have you tried using raw SQL queries ? Also, `drop table` is part of the SQL package

Comment: @nathan and what is the proper place to run this query in vapor3 project?

Comment: Using XCTestCase ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822457/how-to-run-one-time-setup-code-before-executing-any-xctest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/raywenderlich/vapor-til/tree/master/Tests

This requires a DB to be running before you run the tests, but it reverts all migrations at the start of each test run, which gives you a clean DB each time. (Specifically [here](https://github.com/raywenderlich/vapor-til/blob/master/Tests/AppTests/Application%2BTestable.swift#L52))

There's also a `docker-compose.yml` in the root directory for spinning up a completely isolated test environment on Linux

Comment: I've inspected sources and have some concerns - isn't it extremely wasteful to run different instance of the Application (2 times in a row) before _each_ test method? Why don't they use "override class func setUp()" instead?...

Comment: Running the commands (revert and prepare) require an application to boot up. When you provide the application a command it will exit upon completion, so if you do it the way above you don't have much choice for integration tests

Comment: I am using the method from the RW repo as well, and find that tests are very slow due to all the reverting re-migrating going on. Have 8 tests and it takes 8 seconds to run. An identical backend I wrote in Python/Django with identical tests takes only 0.3 seconds..

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that is less resource-intensive, then reverting all migrations every time.

RSpec has a configuration (`use_transactional_fixtures`) that allows wrapping every test in an SQL transaction. When testing is over it will rollback the transaction and in consequence revert all the changes that happened during testing. Relevant [documentation is here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions).

We can implement a similar solution in Vapor. My example test looks like this.

```
final class VaporTests: XCTestCase {

  var app: Application!

  override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    app = try! Application.buildForTesting()
    let conn = try! app.requestPooledConnection(to: .psql).wait()
    try! conn.simpleQuery("BEGIN TRANSACTION").wait()
    try! app.releasePooledConnection(conn, to: .psql)
  }

  override func tearDown() {
    let conn = try! app.requestPooledConnection(to: .psql).wait()
    try! conn.simpleQuery("ROLLBACK").wait()
    try! app.releasePooledConnection(conn, to: .psql)

    super.tearDown()
  }

  func testExample() throws {
    let request = HTTPRequest(method: .GET, url: "my/endpoint/example")
    let wrapper = Request(http: request, using: app)

    let response = try ExampleController().example(wrapper).wait()

    XCTAssertEqual(response, .ok)
  }
}
```

To make sure that I don't encounter issues with concurrency I'm limiting database pool to 1 connection in the test application.

```
func configure(_ config: inout Config, _ env: inout Environment, _ services: inout Services) throws {
  // ... other configurations

  let poolConfig = DatabaseConnectionPoolConfig(maxConnections: 1)
  services.register(poolConfig)
}
```

Many thanks to [Jakub Jatczak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2377694/) for helping me to find out how this happens in Rails.

Comment: Strange, when I try this, the tests never run, they simply hang forever on migrating the database.

Comment: When I saw tests hanging, that usually meant, that I blocked the only accessible connection without releasing it. Make sure that your code around tests doesn't cause deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Quite late to the party but following way also does the `revert` and `migrate` command work. This code does the similar commands as answer given by @0xTim. But I have made use of `Console.framework`:

Mostly we use a `configure.swift` file like below:

```swift
import FluentPostgreSQL
import Vapor

public func configure(_ config: inout Config, _ env: inout Environment, _ services: inout Services) throws {
    // Register providers first
    try services.register(FluentPostgreSQLProvider())

    ...


    /// Configure commands
    var commandConfig = CommandConfig.default()
    commandConfig.useFluentCommands()
    services.register(commandConfig)

    ...

    /// Configure migrations
    services.register { container -> MigrationConfig in
        var migrationConfig = MigrationConfig()
        try migrate(migrations: &migrationConfig)
        return migrationConfig
    }
}
```

Quite late to the party but following code does execute revert and migrate
commands: (I am using `Quick` and `Nimble` so `beforeSuite`. Commented code is there because unless you use above `configure.swift` you can just uncomment the code and make use of `CommandConfig` directly.)

```swift
import Quick
import Vapor
import Console
import FluentPostgreSQL
...
        configuration.beforeSuite {
            let console: Console = Terminal()
//            var commandConfig = CommandConfig()
//            commandConfig.use(RevertCommand(), as: "revert")
//            commandConfig.use(MigrateCommand(), as: "migrate")
            var config = Config.default()
            var env = Environment.testing
            var services = Services.default()

            do {
//                try App.configure(&config, &env, &services)
                let container = try Application(config: config, environment: env, services: services)
                let commandConfig = try container.make(CommandConfig.self)
                let commands = try commandConfig.resolve(for: container).group()
                var input = CommandInput(arguments: ["vapor","revert","--all", "-y"])
                try console.run(commands, input: &input, on: container).wait()
                input = CommandInput(arguments: ["vapor","migrate","-y"])
                try console.run(commands, input: &input, on: container).wait()
            } catch let error {
                console.error(error.localizedDescription)
                exit(1)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For thoses who are seeking another approach that doesnt involve registering new migrations ( and, to me, adding more code complexity ) you can use a **Pre-Action** script for tests target ( ⌘ + < )

[image: Pre-Action Script]

By using a bash script you can create a brand new postgresql database that will be used to build the project for tests only :

```
# Variables 
export IS_TEST=true
export DB_USERNAME="`whoami`"
export DB_DBNAME="BARTENDER_TEST_DB"


#Creating dedicated Postgres DB 
echo "deleting & recreating $DB_DBNAME for user $DB_USERNAME"
psql postgres<< EOF
  DROP DATABASE "$DB_DBNAME";
  CREATE DATABASE "$DB_DBNAME";
  \list
EOF
```

Then in `configure.swift` file you create a `PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig` that matches the newly created database

```
    if let _ = Environment.get("IS_TEST") { // IS_TEST is defined only in Pre-Action script 

        guard let username = Environment.get("DB_USERNAME") else {
            fatalError("Failed to create PostgresConfig - DB_USERNAME in Environment variables")
        }
        guard let databasename = Environment.get("DB_DBNAME") else {
            fatalError("Failed to create PostgresConfig - DB_DBNAME in Environment variables")
        }

        postgresqlConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(
            hostname: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 5432,
            username: username,
            database: databasename,
            password: nil
        )
    } 
    else { /* your other config here */ }

    let database = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: postgresqlConfig)
    ...
```

The big advantage I found in this it that I can even trigger a `vapor build` and `vapor run` from another project that will create a brand new Webservice environment for my continuous integration testings, just by inserting the correct environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I found was to add [PostgresKit](https://github.com/vapor/postgres-kit) to the test target and use it to setup a connection to call my "clean-up" queries.

```swift
@testable import App
import Vapor
import XCTest
import PostgresKit

final class UserTests: XCTestCase {
    
    var pools: EventLoopGroupConnectionPool<PostgresConnectionSource>!
    var postgresDb: PostgresDatabase!
    var eventLoopGroup: EventLoopGroup!
    
    override func setUp() {
        let configuration = PostgresConfiguration(
            hostname: "localhost",
            username: "postgres",
            password: "password",
            database: "db_name"
        )
        
        eventLoopGroup = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 2)
        
        pools = EventLoopGroupConnectionPool(
            source: PostgresConnectionSource(configuration: configuration),
            on: eventLoopGroup
        )
        
        postgresDb = pools.database(logger: Logger.init(label: "TestLogger"))
        
    }
    
    override func tearDown() {
        let _ = try! postgresDb.query("DELETE FROM \(User.schema)").wait()
        try! pools.syncShutdownGracefully()
        try! eventLoopGroup.syncShutdownGracefully()
    }
    
    func testUploadUser() throws {
        let app = Application(.testing)
        defer { app.shutdown() }
        try configure(app)
        
        try app.testable(method: .running).test(.POST, "api/users", beforeRequest: { req in
            try req.content.encode(["firstName" : "Dwide", "lastName" : "Shrewd"])
        }, afterResponse: { res in
            XCTAssertEqual(res.status, .ok)
            let user = try res.content.decode(User.self)
            XCTAssertEqual(user, User(id: user.id, firstName: "Dwide", lastName: "Shrewd"))
        })
    }
    
}
```

And this is my `Package.swift`

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.2
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyVaporProject",
    platforms: [
       .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
    dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-postgres-driver.git", from: "2.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/postgres-kit.git", from: "2.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "App",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Fluent", package: "fluent"),
                .product(name: "FluentPostgresDriver", package: "fluent-postgres-driver"),
                .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor")
            ],
            swiftSettings: [
                // Enable better optimizations when building in Release configuration. Despite the use of
                // the `.unsafeFlags` construct required by SwiftPM, this flag is recommended for Release
                // builds. See <https://github.com/swift-server/guides#building-for-production> for details.
                .unsafeFlags(["-cross-module-optimization"], .when(configuration: .release))
            ]
        ),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: [.target(name: "App")]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "AppTests",
            dependencies: [
                .target(name: "App"),
                .product(name: "XCTVapor", package: "vapor"),
                .product(name: "PostgresKit", package: "postgres-kit")
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

As in previous answers, this requires a stood-up Postgres database, already migrated, ready to take connections before the tests start.